# How can I install sjk into cassandra / nodetool?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I found interesting page in cassandra documentation:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSjk.html

However, when I try it, I get

```
# nodetool sjk --commands
nodetool: Found unexpected parameters: [sjk, --commands]
See 'nodetool help' or 'nodetool help <command>'.
```

I suppose it's because in my standard cassandra 3.11.3 debian instalation the sjk is not installed. However, it seems the sjk is free tool:
https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools

Is it possible to install it in way it integrates with nodetool? How? Or is sjk already integrated and was it just renamed?

Answer (score 0):

While still no idea how to integrate it with nodetool, for case someone who knows even less than me finds this, note that it can be used by downloading as sjk-plus-0.12.jar for example, then run like

```
java -jar sjk-plus-0.12.jar mxdump -s 127.0.01:7199 -q 'java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=*'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Cassandra sjk is not available with nodetool utility but available in datastax. you need to use sjk jar for the metrix and details.